# How the parent is restored after vfork()

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

As vfork creates the child process in the same address space as that of the parent, and when execv() is called on the child then how is the parent process restored, as exec loads the file and runs it in the same address space of the parent and hence the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `execv` follows a true `vfork`, it does some of the work of `fork`: it allocates a new memory space into which to load the new program image and copies inheritable things like environment variables into it.  Meanwhile, even `vfork` saves a bit of the parent’s state on the side, so that `execv` can restore the parent’s stack and instruction pointers once the child is separated.

For example, on Linux [`vfork`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/fork.c#n2124) calls common process-copying code via `_do_fork(CLONE_VFORK | CLONE_VM | SIGCHLD, ...)`.  `copy_mm` reacts to the `CLONE_VM` and just reuses the memory space with no call to `dup_mm`. `_do_fork` meanwhile reacts to the `CLONE_VFORK`, marks the child `vfork_done`, and suspends the caller until the memory space is no longer in use; if this is via [`execve`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/exec.c#n1923), it goes through `exec_mmap` and `mm_release`, which sees the `vfork_done` and wakes the parent.

So, really, `execve` (which also calls `copy_strings`) is always "allocating a new memory space and copying environment variables into it"; after a normal `fork`, however, this is not observable because it happens at the same time as releasing the non-shared space created by the `fork`.

Comment: Hmm,. seems legit. Can you provide some documentation or references?

Comment: @matrixisreal: I couldn't find any real documentation on this subject, but I did finally find the time to go dig through the source.